# Visual Studio how to turn off: Build failed. Do you want to continue debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

When CMake project imported into Visual Studio 2017 build fails, it keeps asking me if I want to continue debugging.

Is it possible to turn off this popup?

Build Failed. Do you want to continue debugging?

Comment: Have you tried Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> On Run, when build or deployment errors occur -> Do not launch? I found this solution but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for me in Visual Studio 2019. I still get the prompt. I'm also using CMake.